# Eclipse 4.3 SR1: when creating a new item (file, class, etc), it doesn't take into account the current selection

Tags: eclipse

I have recently updated to Eclipse 4.3 (SR1, WTP). And I have an issue: when I want to create something: a file, a class, a dir, etc:

- I right click on a dir (or package); e.g. "myDir", or "myPackage"
- the wizard appears, but it doesn't propose "myDir" or "myPackage" as parent element. I need to manually specify it

Do you have any idea what may cause this strange behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

For Java Eclipse will only use the folder / package if the folder you right click on in is a `source` folder (usually the `src` folder). Source folders are defined in the project preferences in the `Java Build Path` `Source` tab.